# I want to display google script single cell value in html text box on button event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am totally new and try to learn the script...pls someone help to resolve this issue

simply i wanna to get google script cell value and show to this in text box

GS code

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppSecure');
  htmlOutput.message = '';
   return htmlOutput.evaluate();
  }

function getValues(){
  var url = "url link";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  var getRange=webAppSheet.getRange(2,1).getValues();
  console.log(getRange);//output value :23:43 PM    Info    Sunil
}
```

html side

```
function getresult(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) {
   var iterm=document.getElementById("dname").value;
 }).getValues(name);
 console.log(name);
}


 <input type="text" id="dsrn" />
 <input type="button" id="button2" value="ID_Search1" onclick="getresult()"/>
```

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't wish to create a doGet() so here's the same thing done with a dialog:

GS:

```
function launchMyDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'),'Dialog Title');
}

function getMyValue() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  return sh.getRange(2,1).getValue();
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="txt"/>
  <br /><input type="button" value="Get Data" onClick="getValue();" />
  <script>
    function getValue() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler((v) => {document.getElementById("txt").value = v;})
      .getMyValue();
    }
    console.log("my code")
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]